# Multiple X-UA-Compatible meta tag in a single site

Tags: html, wordpress, http, meta-tags, x-ua-compatible

I know this isn't the best way to code a site, but this is an emergency and I need to figure this out asap.

I have a Wordpress site (completely irrelevant in this question, though), with two particular pages.

One page must use the IE's Quirks Mode, which I have successfully invoked using a hack (adding a comment at the beginning, and also by using http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5")

Another page must use IE 9 as its document type.
If I visit one of these pages, IE invokes the correct document type.
Problem begins when I go from one page to another; the new page (which is linked from the original page) KEEPS the previous document type.

Here's an example:

Page 1 has Quirks mode enabled.
Page 2 has IE 9 as document type.

I goto page 1 by typing in the URL.
*IE renders it correctly using Quirks Mode*
Then I click a link leading me to page 2.
*IE renders page 2 still as Quirks mode, even though it is specified in the header to use IE 9*

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Have you tried some meta no-cache tags on the quirks mode page? And, maybe using x-ua-compatible of edge for the IE 9 page? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Comment: If you've specified your X-UA-Compatible correctly; this won't happen. Do you have a repro URL?

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried the suggestions from MS site, but didn't fix the problem. Also tried IE=edge. Here are the repro urls: Page 1 (using Quirks - actually, all other pages in the site except page 2 uses quirks) http://bit.ly/rpBmBa Page 2: http://bit.ly/qNHgMu

Comment: Now that I think about it, the source of the problem MIGHT be my developer tools in IE being open and setting the document type to one type constantly. IF this is the problem, how can I disable the developer tools from doing this?

Comment: How about moving the top script blocks down to the head section?

Comment: <3 Jen-  It works fine now. The solution to the problem was actually disabling my developer tools.

Answer (score 5):

This may be helpful for IE issues.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10" >
```

Comment: Can you explain what sort of issues this should fix?

Comment: Above code is fixing default IE quirks mode to correct mode as we given above. If we not used above then browser is getting quirks mode and not rendering properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Don't put anything above the Doctype. That will throw IE into quirks mode. Drop the JS below the Doctype.

It's probably caching. How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried the suggestions from MS site, but didn't fix the problem. Also tried IE=edge. Here are the repro urls: Page 1 (using Quirks - actually, all other pages in the site except page 2 uses quirks) http://bit.ly/rpBmBa             Page 2: http://bit.ly/qNHgMu